# Gradle ADT 0.4 error: android.buildToolsVersion is missing

Tags: android, gradle, adt

Attempting to build my Android project using the latest ADT tools release of Gradle, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'.
> android.buildToolsVersion is missing!
```

Using Gradle 1.6, Android plugin 0.4.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure that you've downloaded the latest ADT, SDK, Platform and Build tools.  Then add this to your gradle build.

```
android {
     buildToolsVersion "17.0"
     compileSdkVersion 15
}
```

[credit to the adt mailing group.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.adt.devel/461)

Note: It is important to put the **"** around the 17.0 as shown - otherwise that will not work

Comment: This answer only works for a specific version of the Android Build-tools, which you may not have installed.  My answer below shows where to get the correct buildToolsVersion for any Build-tools you have installed.

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  With gradle 1.7 and Android plugin 0.5.6, setting the buildToolsVersion in quotes still results in "android.buildToolsVersion is missing".

Answer (score 7):

The buildToolsVersion value depends upon which version you downloaded from Google.

Assuming you installed the Android SDK, run "android" from the command-line, to open the Android SDK Manager.  In the left column you'll see Tools | Android SDK Build-tools.  That tells you whether or not you've installed the Build-tools yet.

After installing the Build-tools, look at the second column, labelled "Rev."  It has the Build-tools version to use for gradle's buildToolVersion.

[image]